# gpu-manager error

Tags: upgrade, vmware

I have upgrading Ubuntu Server from 16.04 to 18.04 but after first restart, the GUI doesn't start correctly, running under VMWare Workstation 15.5. Looking in the system log file, I see this error:

> gpu-manager[2160]: Error: can't open
>   /lib/modules/4.15.0-88-generic/updates/dkms

I have searched Google for that error message without success.

Only the GUI doesn't start correctly, the server works correctly from command line and I can access the Samba shares correctly.

EDIT: while upgrading Ubuntu to 18.04, I also upgraded VMWare to the latest version (15.5). But this is not enough: the VM itself has to be upgraded as well to version 15.5. Now the GUI is correctly displayed. But gpu-manager error is still there. And after a few seconds, there is a popup telling there was a system crash without further detail. Then the system seems to work OK except the desktop background is black.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What does `update grub` display?

Comment: In my case I was playing with different kernels. Kernel modules could not be generated for kernel because of Nvidia drivers were incompatible with that kernel modules. I've just removed those kernels and used those that were working without issues.

Comment: @Gryu update-grub said:Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-88-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-88-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-174-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-174-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
done

Comment: Please try kernel bootoption `nogpumanager`

Comment: @nobody Thanks. The option nogpumanager solved the issue, at least no more error about gpu manager (of course). Until now I don't see any adverse effect (I have no specific application making specific use of GPU).